# Is it ok to write a follow-up paper for a paper which has been accepted but not available online yet?

Tags: publications, citations, peer-review

My field is image processing and computer vision.

I wrote a paper and presented it in a conference in November 2015. The paper is yet to be available in IEEE Xplore. Now, I've written a follow-up paper which describes an improved version of the method which was presented earlier.

Does the fact that the paper is still not available in Xplore, affect my submission in anyway? The conference does not allow submission of any supplemental material, so I also cannot attach the previous paper as a supplementary material. Can somebody help me regarding this?

Moreover, I've read that putting reference in abstract section is generally not recommended, however, in my case I have put a reference to my previous paper in asbtract because I'm mentioning that this is a follow-up work which shows an improved version of method presented in [previous_work].

Please help.

Comment: Your question needs proofreading. Would you please rewrite that in a more illustrative way?

Comment: @Roboticist: I've just done that, sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely OK to write a follow-up paper even though the previous paper has not been published yet. There is no requirement to wait.

When you submit your new paper for review, you need to give the reviewers the opportunity to compare your old paper against the new paper. If you submit to a journal that allows attachments, putting the old paper there would be an option. Another option would be adding a private URL to the bibliography entry of your older paper, or to cite a preprint of your paper instead (if is already available).

Comment: I am submitting to a conference and it does not allow even supplementary material suission. Does IEEE copyright allows putting your paper in arxiv before it is available in Xplore?

Comment: @stalin See https://www.ieee.org/documents/author_version_faq.pdf